# Issue on scanf input receiving

Tags: c, pointers, integer, segmentation-fault, char

I'm currently learning C, as learning, I decide to make a small project to make sure I understand the lessons. I decided to make a simple login system with a pre-set password inside a variable. Now I'm very blur on using or converting variables in C, this was the case of why.

```c
// Library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Main
int main(){
    system("clear");
    for (int AUTHORIZED = 0; AUTHORIZED != 1;){ // Sign in function loop
        printf("Welcome to the program!\n\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("Please identify yourself.");
        sleep(3);
        system("clear");
        printf("Username : ");
        char USER[99999999]; // Variable set (Type as character array so it can receive string)
        scanf("%s", USER); // Scan the input
        printf("%s", USER); // Print the username
    }
    }
```

Now when compiling, it didn't give me any error. Though when I run it, it gives this error
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I tried to fix it by changing the variable type to `int`. The result is conflicting type between `int` type and `int *` type.

```c
int USER[99999999]; 
scanf("%i",USER); 
printf("%i", USER);
```

```c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:19:18: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   19 |         printf("%i", USER);
      |                 ~^   ~~~~
      |                  |   |
      |                  int int *
      |                 %ls
```

Comment: `char USER[99999999];` is far too large for the stack. `int USER[99999999];` is four times more than that assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`. Do you really expect a username to be almost 100 million characters long?